# ASP.NET MVC limit Table view depending on user role

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I'm building a web app for tracking holidays across a company that has different sites. I need to display list of employees on my admin page but I only want Managers/Admins to view the employee list related to them based on their sites (they may have one or many).

On my Admin page, I have created a table of employees from my database, which displays all employees and links to their details on each row.

Controller :

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchString)
    {
        var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Area).Include(e => e.Discipline).Include(e => e.Shift).Include(e => e.Site).Include(e => e.UserRole);
        return View(employees.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10 ));


    }
```

Model:

```
 public partial class Employee

 public Employee()
    {

        this.HolidayRequestForms = new HashSet<HolidayRequestForm>();
    }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is Required")]
    public string EmailID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public int DisciplineID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public int ALCategory { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AwardedLeave { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TotalHoursThisYear { get; set; }
    public int HoursCarriedForward { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntitlementRemainingThisYear { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int SickLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SickLeaveEntitlement { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SickLeaveEntitlementRemaining { get; set; }
    public int StudyLeaveEntitlement { get; set; }
    public int StudyLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StudyLeaveRemaining { get; set; }
    public int ExamLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public int ForceMajeure { get; set; }
    public int BereavementLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public int MaternityLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public int ParentalLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public int AdoptionLeaveTaken { get; set; }

    public string LoginErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
    public virtual Discipline Discipline { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<HolidayRequestForm> HolidayRequestForms { get; set; }
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

And View (just the table section):

```
  <table class="table table-striped">

        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>

            <th>
                Start Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Area
            </th>
            <th>
                Discipline
            </th>
            <th>
                Site Name
            </th>

            <th>
                AL Category
            </th>
            <th>
                Hours CF
            </th>
            <th>
                Awarded Leave
            </th>
            <th>
                Total Hours This Year
            </th>
            <th>
                Hours Taken
            </th>
            <th>
                Hours Remaining
            </th>
            <th>
                Role
            </th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area.Area1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discipline.Discipline1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Site.SiteName)
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ALCategory)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoursCarriedForward)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AwardedLeave)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalHoursThisYear)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoursTaken)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntitlementRemainingThisYear)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserRole.RoleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeID }, new { @class = "btn-xs btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmployeeID }, new { @class = "btn-xs btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.EmployeeID }, new { @class = "btn-xs btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }


    </table>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

I'd like it so that only managers/Admins assigned to certain sites could only view those sites and none else. Regular Users don't have access to this page.

Is this possible to do in mvc??

Comment: Yes... it is possible to do in MVC. You should filter the data from the database and display it in the UI.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya So would I be just using a SQLserver query to extract the data to be shown in the UI?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server to store your data, then yes you need to query to SQL Server to extract the data you want.

Comment: yep I am, thank you, that will be get me started in the right direction